# Add conditional rendering logic inside React child ui component or inside parent component

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I am using [Atomic design](https://medium.com/@janelle.wg/atomic-design-pattern-how-to-structure-your-react-application-2bb4d9ca5f97) to structure my React components.

A certain ui child component (an atom) should be shown or not based on a value (prop).

Is it a better practice to add the conditional rendering inside this child component like:

```
const Child = ({ show }: Props) => {
  return show ? (
    <span>Foo</span>;
  ) : null
}
```

or add the conditional rendering part inside the parent component:

```
{ show && <Child /> }
```

What is a better practice: Add conditional rendering logic inside React child ui component or inside parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on what you want to achieve. Basically there is no **significant** difference between these two ways of conditional rendering when it comes to performance or something.

The question is: do you want to conditionaly render Child at all or make Child configurable and control span rendering inside it? It's more like architectural/design decision than code quality or good practice problem.

Anyway... There is no one golden rule. It depends on what you need in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach is better since it would be readable code and also avoids rendering the Child component in case 'show' is falsy.